# Existence of a prime in an interval that is not a linear combination of two specified primes?

Tags: prime-numbers

If $ n = \left( \frac{p+q}{2 } \right) + p q  :p,q \in\mathbb{P}-\left\{2\right\} $

> Can we show there exists a prime number $\theta : \sqrt{2n} \leq \theta \leq n $ and $\theta$ is not a linear combination of $p$ and $q$ (restricted to positive coefficients)?

I know we can show there exists a prime number in the interval $[\sqrt{2n},n]$, if $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2}} \geq2$ using Bertrand's postulate...

Comment: Am I missing something? Since $(p,q) = 1$, any integer is a linear combination of $p$ and $q$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $(p,q)=1$

Comment: @BradGraham gcd, but you said positive coefficients

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the positive coefficient condition orignally, hence the edit